# Add column to MSHFlexGrid in VB

Tags: forms, vb6, datagridviewcolumn

I am maintaining a VB6 application that contains a MSHFlexGrid control that is populated from an ADODB record set.  I have been asked to add a column to those displayed in the grid.  My understanding from my research is that I need to:

1) Revise the SQL that creates the record set to include the additional column.  (DONE.)

2) Revise the control on the form so that it displays an additional column.  (DONE.)

3) In the property pages for the MSHFlexGrid control indicate the new column.  (STUCK.)

So it should be EASY to add another column in the VB interface, right?  But I am stumped.  There is no "Add" button.  Editing an existing column doesn't work.  I have clicked, right-clicked, double-clicked, and even simultaneously clicked all over the property page trying to find a sub-menu to no avail.  The references I am finding all talk about how to add make changes to the VB6 interface

I think that there must have been a wizard invoked to add the original columns.  Short of calling up Harry Potter, I do not know what to try next!

Comment: Are the columns visible in design mode or only at run-time?

Comment: They are visible in design mode.